# How to insert a child node in Powershell when parent is empty

Tags: xml, powershell

From this :

```
<products>
</products>
```

I want to get this :

```
<products>
    <product code="id1">
</products>
```

What's the right syntax ? I tried this but does not seem to work :

```
$newproduct= $products.CreateElement("product")
$newproduct.SetAttribute("code", "");                        
$newproduct.code="id1" 
$products.AppendChild($newproduct)
```

Solution given below almost works except AppendChild does not work on null value. I've typed the given example exactly on Powershell 2.

[image]

Comment: In what way did that not work? What was the result of that code? What is `$products` in that code? How did you determine that this code didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an attribute node and append it to the `<product>` node's attributes:

```psh
[xml]$xml = '<products></products>'

$newproduct = $xml.CreateElement('product')
$attr = $xml.CreateAttribute('code')
$attr.Value = 'id1'
$newproduct.Attributes.Append($attr)

$products = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//products')
$products.AppendChild($newproduct)
```

Result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<products>
  <product code="id1" />
</products>
```

Demonstration (PowerShell v2):

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.3662
BuildVersion                   6.0.6002.18111
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1

PS C:\> [xml]$xml = '<products></products>'
PS C:\> $newproduct = $xml.CreateElement('product')
PS C:\> $attr = $xml.CreateAttribute('code')
PS C:\> $attr.Value = 'id1'
PS C:\> $newproduct.Attributes.Append($attr)

#text
-----
id1

PS C:\> $products = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//products')
PS C:\> $products.AppendChild($newproduct)

code
----
id1

PS C:\> $xml.Save([Console]::Out) + "`n"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<products>
  <product code="id1" />
</products>
```

Comment: Error cannot AppendChild on null value

Comment: @user310291 Update your question with your current (complete) code.

Comment: Actually I tried your exact code on Powershell v2 but seems I got a different result.

Comment: @user310291 The code I posted works just fine in PowerShell v2. I'm not making this up. If it doesn't work for you: please provide evidence.

Comment: @user310291 You select the node `<products>`, but you don't assign it to the variable `$products`. You need this: `$products = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//products')` before you can do `$products.AppendChild($newproduct)`.

Comment: Just a subsequent question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501169/why-error-system-string-does-not-contain-a-method-named-appendchild