# Why Error "System.String does not contain a method named 'AppendChild'"

Tags: powershell

Why does this PowerShell Script not work:

```psh
[xml]$xml = '<products></products>'

$newproduct = $xml.CreateElement('product')
$attr = $xml.CreateAttribute('code')
$attr.Value = 'id1'
$newproduct.Attributes.Append($attr)

$products = $xml.products
$products.AppendChild($newproduct)
```

Error is

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'AppendChild'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $products.AppendChild($newproduct)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

If I replace

```psh
$products = $xml.products
```

by

```psh
$products = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//products')
```

it will work, but I'd like to know why first syntax does not work because it is illogical for me. `$xml.products` should be a valid XML object and thus provide the method `AppendChild()`.

Comment: If google brought you here because [System.String] does not contain a method named "StartsWith" or "IndexOf" or any other thing it actually does have, its probably because you have something like `$val = "DefinitelyAString"` and are trying to use something like `$val::IndexOf("ef")`. This super terrible error should say "Use `$val.IndexOf("ef")` instead.

Comment: Thank you @StingyJack exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$xml.products` does not reference the `products` node itself, but the *contents* of the `products` node. Since `products` is empty, it evaluates to an empty string.

To get to the `products` node you could also use:

```
$Products = $xml.FirstChild 
$Products.AppendChild($newproduct)
```

or, more specifically:

```
$Products = $xml.ChildNodes.Where({$_.Name -eq "products"}) |Select-Object -First 1
$Products.AppendChild($newproduct)
```

But `SelectSingleNode()` will probably serve you just fine

Comment: I get Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlElement] does not contain a method named 'Where'. 5.0

Comment: this does not work, but the other answer with SelectSingleNode saved me!

Comment: @McVitas Thanks for the heads up, fixed

Answer (score 3):

```
$xml.configuration.SelectSingleNode("connectionStrings").AppendChild($newnode)
```

would work fine, but an interesting & dirty hack: given this empty node:

```
  <connectionStrings>    
  </connectionStrings>
```

the script

```
$xml.configuration.connectionStrings.AppendChild($newnode)
```

gives a "`Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'AppendChild'`" error

but this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
        <!-- random comment -->
  </connectionStrings>
```

works perfectly fine